# Replace value of nested object with variable structure

Tags: javascript

I've an object like this:

```js
const obj = {a: {x: 0, y: 0}}
```

that could be also:

```js
const obj = {a: {x: 0, y: 0}, b: {x: 10, y: 3}, abcd: {x: -1, y: 0}}
```

So, the `obj` can have more than one key and with variables key names.
I need to replace each `x` value with a a string like this `${x}%` so the `x` value + the percentage symbol.

How can I do that?

The expected results should be:

```js
const obj = {a: {x: 0, y: 0}} // {a: {x: '0%', y: 0}}
const obj = {a: {x: 0, y: 0}, b: {x: 10, y: 3}, abcd: {x: -1, y: 0}} // {a: {x: '0%', y: 0}, b: {x: '10%', y: 3}, abcd: {x: '-1%', y: 0}}
```

I tried looping the object but I don't know if there is a smartest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {a: {x: 0, y: 0}, b: {x: 10, y: 3}, abcd: {x: -1, y: 0}}

let result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => {
    return [k,{...v,x:`${v.x}%`}]
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the object recursively. So no matter how deep the object goes every given `key` that matches gets a `suffix`.

I also make sure to create a copy of the object to prevent altering the original object(s).

```js
const obj = {a: {x: 0, y: 0}, b: {x: 10, y: 3}, abcd: {x: -1, y: 0}};

const addSuffixToObj = (obj, key, suffix) => {
  const copy = {...obj};

  Object.keys(copy).forEach((prop) => {
    if (typeof copy[prop] === 'object') {
      copy[prop] = addSuffixToObj(copy[prop], key, suffix);
    }else if(prop === key){
      copy[prop] = copy[prop] + suffix;
    }
  });
  
  return copy;
}

// Add "%" to all "x" keys
const result = addSuffixToObj(obj, 'x', '%');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array of object keys and then use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), it's a method that executes provided function for every element of array(here - for every object key):

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => obj[el].x = `${obj[el].x}%`)
```